# Android file to byte[] and byte[] to file

Tags: android, sqlite, blob, android-file, android-fileprovider

I am tring to get file from user with file explorer and save it to SQLITE database as BLOB. What I have done is I get file and convert it to byte[] with the code as

```
>     private byte[] convertFiletoByte(String filePath) throws IOException{
>           InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath.toString()); 
>           ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>           byte[] b = new byte[1024];
>           int bytesRead;
>           while((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
>              bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
>           }
>           byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
>           byte[] dataToSave = Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
>           
>           return dataToSave;
>       }
```

Then I save it to database. Since here it all looks fine.

When I try to get file back from database and save it as a file again the content of file changes.
I am tring to convert byte to file with:

```
private void reconvertBytetoFile(byte[] bytes) throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = 
                new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Download/test2.txt"); 
        fileOuputStream.write(bytes);
        fileOuputStream.close();
    }
```

The main problem in here is the output is totally different from the input. Any correction or idea would be great. :)

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: You need to undo the base64 encoding.

Comment: Thank you for fast responde decoding solve it. I forgot that I encoded the input :) @Henry Will this code work with other types of documents such as .doc . And will decoding cause any trouble with images inside of document?